# My Augmented Reality app has insufficient warning about parental supervision according to Google Play's policy

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

My app has been rejected by Google Play twice over this issue:

> If your app uses Augmented Reality, you must include a safety warning upon launch of the app that contains the following:
>
> - An appropriate message about the importance of parental supervision.
> - A reminder to be aware of physical hazards in the real world (e.g., be aware of your surroundings).

I added a message which pops up when AR section is loaded "While using this app please be aware of your surroundings. It is recommended that younger children have supervision when using Augmented Reality." Apparently, it was insufficient. I downloaded a bunch of AR apps and none of them have a message like that. Any ideas what this message should be? Should it pop-up every time the app is loaded or just once when installed? I reached out to Google Policy's team and I'm waiting for their reply as well.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately your questions sounds like this is not the correct place for it. Rather contact the [Google Play - Support](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7100415?hl=en)

Comment: Were you able to get a resolution for this? One of our apps was recently flagged with this violation during a routine update.

Comment: Our app got rejected as well, and they cite the "Designed for Families Program" Requirements and my app is not even part of that. From the rejection message it's not clear if my privacy statement is insufficient (which is pretty simple because I don't collect any data whatsoever, free app, not even ads), or maybe this warning.

Comment: I'm in a similar situation. I'll let you know how I got on.

Comment: @derHugo - but this is unanswered in Google Play support so that is not very helpful. Of course not a code question either, maybe there is some other StackExchange site for these. https://support.google.com/googleplay/thread/15123844?hl=en

Comment: Dude, did you solve your problem? Same thing is happening to me, I've been rejected twice, not sure what they want me to do. Or, if any of the below answers helped you, you may accept it.

Answer (score 4):

Whilst this is unusually a non-code based question, I was able to resolve the problem and get our app approved by Google with the following text.

> Always ask a grown-up before using the DinoSaw app. Watch out out for
>   other people when using DinoSaw and be aware of your surroundings.
>
> Parents and guardians please note: whilst using Augmented Reality
>   there is a tendency for users to step backwards to view dinosaurs.

I think the trick is simply to consider your app in context of the appropriate environment and add more than just their token text. - Our app is for augmented reality dinosaurs designed specifically for kids. They will accidentally bump/back into other people whilst they are absorbed by the content.

Dinosaurs seem to have that affect on little people it seems.

[image: Augmented Reality dinosaurs: Be careful]

I also added an amusing graphic to humour the situation - Looks like it worked :)

Comment: Anyone still having this issue? I have tried multiple wanring messages similar to these and still get rejected for AR. Popup popup up shows up everytime they enter the application. This app used to work just fine but then start being rejected only recently. Attached is the most recent. I have downloaded other AR Apps that are similar or less. i.stack.imgur.com/Wqtiz.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I got this message on an app update too.

In addition to making sure the message was crystal clear and including a warning icon/image as @Ghoul Fool suggested in another answer, I also make sure the message was triggered in the OnResume function for the AR activity.

My update was accepted wiht this change - it's not possible to know what exactly  was the trigger for the acceptance but sharing here in case the 'OnResume' change makes the difference for others also.

```js
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
       
        //Do your other OnResume work here

        //Display an AR warning for kids as required by Google Play store guidelines
        warningARDialog()
    }
```