# Google Play App Rejected-Special restrictions: Augmented Reality

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, augmented-reality, arcore

We currently have an app on the app store that's been up for months now. Every release we've pushed has been approved just fine. The last vesion we tried to push we changed one thing and it was rejected and I am trying to figure out why. I know it has to do with augmented reality (which has also been in the app since the first release).

Here is what changed and our issue getting it approved.

The app was created with Unity3d. in previous releases you entered a login screen, logged in and were taken to a content selection screen in which the user selected which content they wanted to download and view. It then downloads the content. Everything here is fine. What changed was we noticed the analytics we were using for capturing how long the user was in the app was being reset because the permissions window that pops up when an AR scene is in use the first time calls OnApplicationPause. Our Analytics has an OnApplicationPause where if the user has the app paused (or just running in the background) it will end the current session and restart when the user brings back the app into focus. Because of this that popup messes with sessions. So we moved a check to determine if permissions were granted to the front of the app before they get to that content screen.

Because of this change Google has rejected the app pointing to the below policy:

**Special restrictions:**
If your app uses Augmented Reality, you must include a safety warning immediately upon launch of the AR section. The warning should contain the following:
An appropriate message about the importance of parental supervision.
A reminder to be aware of physical hazards in the real world (e.g., be aware of your surroundings).

So they are getting the same warning message about camera usage that they are then agreeing to its just not happening right when the AR camera is in use.

Can we just add our own message here? Does it have to be the permissions message in that scene only? I am not understanding if they are already aggreeing to those permssions why they would reject the app just because it isnt being displayed in that specific scene.

What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: The thing is that Google reviewed your app and decided they will reject this app as it is (it could happen anytime). It's not about the change you've made - Google updated their rules and you need to comply with them as they ask.

Comment: They might have missed out previously. Recent years the app preview has been very strict. Yes. You can customize your own message. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57188669/my-augmented-reality-app-has-insufficient-warning-about-parental-supervision-acc

Comment: @rootpanthera totally get about complying. I just submitted a release update 2 weeks and passed no issue. The only that changed was where I placed the ask for permissions. So I was seeing if it requires the camera persmission at that screen or if I was able to create my own so it didn't interfere with the apps OnApplicationPause functionality like joantoh has commented about. The compliance is very vague when it comes to a solution when it does exists.

Comment: So I added a warning message directed at the policy when they enter the app that they see every time and mist click continue to proceed, but still rejected. Now I'm really confused. Any ideas?

Comment: Same app is approved on iOS which is odd cause I usually have more of an issue with Apple rejecting then Google.